# unable to get value of the property 'msie'

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

I am currently getting the following error in IE9 - unable to get value of the property 'msie' object is null or undefined, for the below Jquery function.

I am using Jquery-1.8.2 plugin for the below jquery function.

```
  if(!options.buildOnce){
        $(window).resize(function() {
            if(!options.buildOnce && $.browser.msie){
                if($inBox.data("timeout")){
                    clearTimeout($inBox.data("timeout"));
                }
                $inBox.data("timeout", setTimeout(columnizeIt, 200));
            }else if(!options.buildOnce){
                columnizeIt();
            }else{

            }
        });
    }
```

Please advice, as to where I may be going wrong.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.browser has been deprecated since jQuery 1.4, it was removed in 1.8 (some say 1.9, but at any rate, its gone.)

I found this at http://pupunzi.open-lab.com/2012/08/14/jquery-1-8-and-browser-detection/

Answer (score 0):

You can try using navigator.userAgent to detect which browser.

Not sure about it's reliability in these days but at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_useragent.asp you can find a short description and testable example to see how it works with your browsers.